# how to swipe cells in uitableview left and right, showing an image on left and an image on right

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As illustrated, what I need to achieve is when swiping left, a button with an image shows up, the blue one, and when swiping right the green button shows up, how to do this? i use swift and xcode 6.4

This is what i tried before asking, I was able to show two options with text in the right of a cell, but i don't want that, what is needed is in the illustration, and as said, the buttons need to be images not text.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can subclass `UITableViewCell` to incorporate a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that manipulates the cell's `contentView`s frame and add your buttons behind the `contentView`.

To see how this can work it detail, I added example code on how to do that below for reference. This also adds a tap gesture recognizer to 'close' the action on tap instead of selecting the cell.

Also, as requested in the comments, here is a gif of how this works (showing the colors of the buttons on the side as an indication of action, but you can easily modify the `contentView`'s frame to be completely overlapping the buttons in your subclass.)

[image]

```
//
//  MWSwipeableTableViewCell.swift
//  MW UI Toolkit
//
//  Created by Jan Greve on 02.12.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Markenwerk GmbH. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol MWSwipeableTableViewCellDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
  func swipeableTableViewCellDidRecognizeSwipe(cell : MWSwipeableTableViewCell)
  func swipeableTableViewCellDidTapLeftButton(cell : MWSwipeableTableViewCell)
  func swipeableTableViewCellDidTapRightButton(cell : MWSwipeableTableViewCell)
}

class MWSwipeableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  weak var delegate : MWSwipeableTableViewCellDelegate?
  var animationOptions : UIViewAnimationOptions = [.AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState]
  var animationDuration : NSTimeInterval = 0.5
  var animationDelay : NSTimeInterval = 0
  var animationSpingDamping : CGFloat = 0.5
  var animationInitialVelocity : CGFloat = 1
  private weak var leftWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
  private weak var rightWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
  var buttonWidth :CGFloat = 80 {
    didSet(val) {
      if let r = self.rightWidthConstraint {
        r.constant = self.buttonWidth
      }
      if let l = self.leftWidthConstraint {
        l.constant = self.buttonWidth
      }
    }
  }
  private weak var panRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
  private weak var buttonCancelTap : UITapGestureRecognizer!

  private var beginPoint : CGPoint = CGPointZero
  weak var rightButton : UIButton! {
    willSet(val) {
      if let r = self.rightButton {
        r.removeFromSuperview()
      }
      if let b = val {
        self.addSubview(b)
        b.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[v]-(0)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
        let wc = NSLayoutConstraint(item: b, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.buttonWidth)
        b.addConstraint(wc)
        self.rightWidthConstraint = wc
        self.sendSubviewToBack(b)
      }
    }
  }
  weak var leftButton : UIButton! {
    willSet(val) {
      if let l = self.leftButton {
        l.removeFromSuperview()
      }
      if let b = val {
        self.addSubview(b)
        b.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-(0)-[v]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
        let wc = NSLayoutConstraint(item: b, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.buttonWidth)
        b.addConstraint(wc)
        self.leftWidthConstraint = wc
        self.sendSubviewToBack(b)
      }
    }
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
  }

  private func commonInit() {

    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didPan:")
    pan.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    self.panRecognizer = pan

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap:")
    tap.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.buttonCancelTap = tap

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  }


  override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let tap = gestureRecognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
      if tap == self.buttonCancelTap {
                return self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0
        }
      else {
        return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
      }
    }
    else if let pan = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
      let trans = pan.translationInView(self)
      if abs(trans.x) > abs(trans.y) {
        return true
      }
      else if self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0 {
        return true
      }
      else {
        return false
      }
    }
    else {
      return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
    }
  }


  func didTap(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping, initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
      self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
      }, completion: nil)
  }

  func didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .Began:
        self.delegate?.swipeableTableViewCellDidRecognizeSwipe(self)
      self.beginPoint = sender.locationInView(self)
      self.beginPoint.x -= self.contentView.frame.origin.x

    case .Changed:
      let now = sender.locationInView(self)
      let distX = now.x - self.beginPoint.x
      if distX <= 0 {
        let d = max(distX,-(self.contentView.frame.size.width-self.buttonWidth))
        if d > -self.buttonWidth*2 || self.rightButton != nil || self.contentView.frame.origin.x > 0 {
          self.contentView.frame.origin.x = d
        }
        else {
          sender.enabled = false
          sender.enabled = true
        }
      }
      else {
        let d = min(distX,self.contentView.frame.size.width-self.buttonWidth)
        if d < self.buttonWidth*2 || self.leftButton != nil || self.contentView.frame.origin.x < 0 {
          self.contentView.frame.origin.x = d
        }
        else {
          sender.enabled = false
          sender.enabled = true
        }
      }

    default:
        delegate?.swipeableTableViewCellDidRecognizeSwipe(self)
      let offset = self.contentView.frame.origin.x
      if offset > self.buttonWidth && self.leftButton != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping, initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.contentView.frame.origin.x = self.buttonWidth
          }, completion: nil)
      }
      else if -offset > self.buttonWidth && self.rightButton != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping, initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.contentView.frame.origin.x = -self.buttonWidth
          }, completion: nil)
      }
      else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping, initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
          }, completion: nil)
      }
    }
    }

  func closeButtonsIfShown(animated:Bool = true) -> Bool {
    if self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0 {
      if animated {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping, initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
          self.panRecognizer.enabled = false
          self.panRecognizer.enabled = true
          }, completion: nil)
      }
      else {
        self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
        self.panRecognizer.enabled = false
        self.panRecognizer.enabled = true

      }
      return true
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }

  func didTapButton(sender:UIButton!) {
    if let d = delegate {
      if let l = self.leftButton {
        if sender == l {
          d.swipeableTableViewCellDidTapLeftButton(self)
        }
      }
      if let r = self.rightButton {
        if sender == r {
          d.swipeableTableViewCellDidTapRightButton(self)
        }
      }
    }
    self.closeButtonsIfShown(false)
  }

  override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let showing = self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0
    if !showing {
      super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
      self.rightButton?.alpha = showing || !highlighted ? 1 : 0
      self.leftButton?.alpha = showing || !highlighted ? 1 : 0
    }
  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let showing = self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0
    if !showing {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      self.rightButton?.alpha = showing || !selected ? 1 : 0
      self.leftButton?.alpha = showing || !selected ? 1 : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but, if this is to be able to show an image instead of text?
now how to swipe to the left to show the green one?

Comment: You can add whatever view you please. As for the swipe, like I said, use a PanGestureRecognizer and figure out the manipulations to the `contentView`s frame that are needed to reflect the pan action in question. As a reference, my implementation for this is about 300 LOC in Swift.

Comment: Jan, are you able to give information so as to establish this as an authoritative reference over time? As you are able to edit it at your leisure?

Comment: @Drew, I will come back at this on Tuesday, editing this answer to give more detail with a narrowed down implementation.

Comment: @JanGreve , I can see you added a whole new code, could you paste an animated gif of the final result? thanks a lot.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen, did do that :)

Comment: I am using the same code in Swift 3 , while the Pan gesture is recognized properly , the tap  gesture is never called on taping the right / left buttons.Any idea why this could happen ?

Comment: Hi @SmokeDispenser, Can you please help to implement the above scenario using objective c.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser, thanks for you answer! You said "you can easily modify the contentView's frame to be completely overlapping the buttons in your subclass"... I'm having problems with achieving that. Can you give me any clue?

Comment: Well, exactly like that: contentView.frame = whatever CGRect you want.

Answer (score 5):

I could achieved the same result using the swipe gesture recognizer. Hope this would help.

1. Create a table with prototype cell.
2. Add button both on left side and right side of the cell with image for default control state (you can change the image based on the state control state).
3. Add a container view (here it is mainView)on top of the cell covering the entire cell area.
4. Create a `TableViewCustomCell` by subclassing the `UITableViewCell`
5. Change the class of the prototype cell to the custom `TableViewCustomCell`
6. Use the following code in `TableViewCustomCell`

Swift Code :

```
    import UIKit

    class TableViewCustomCell:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
    @IBAction func leftButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("leftTap")
    }

    @IBAction func rightButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
         print("rightTap")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("swipe:"))
        leftSwipe.direction = .Left;
        self.mainView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("swipe:"))
        rightSwipe.direction = .Right;
        self.mainView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    func swipe(sender:AnyObject)
    {
        let swipeGesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = sender as! UISwipeGestureRecognizer
        if(swipeGesture.direction == .Left)
        {
            var frame:CGRect = self.mainView.frame;
            frame.origin.x = -self.leftButton.frame.width;
            self.mainView.frame = frame;
        }
        else if(swipeGesture.direction == .Right)
        {
            var frame:CGRect = self.mainView.frame;
            frame.origin.x = +self.rightButton.frame.width;
            self.mainView.frame = frame;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime." - I faced this compile time error while trying your way.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to go at this, you could look into one of the many existing libraries such as BMXSwipeableCell by Massimiliano Bigatti https://github.com/mbigatti/BMXSwipableCell, where you can either look at the source code or copy it completely.

Another approach is reading through one of the following two great tutorials:

**How to Make a Swipeable TableViewCell With Actions - Without Going Nuts ScrollViews** - by Ellen Shapiro:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

**How to Make a Gesture-Driven To-Do List App Like Clear in Swift** - by Audrey Tam: https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1

To give you a quick idea, the gist is as follows:

i. Create a custom `TableViewCell`

ii. Add a `UIPangestureRecognizer`

iii. Keep a reference to the original `contentView` frame, this is necessary since you will be swiping(panning) this `contentView` left and right. And keep a reference to the originalCenter of the cell.

iv. Add the images, buttons, or other views you want to reveal to the cell

What happens is that you will guide the appearance of your swipeable cell through the three stages of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`: `UIGestureStateBegan, UIGestureStateChanged, UIGestureStateEnded`

1. `UIGestureStateBegan`: First check if this a horizontal pan, and not a vertical one in the `UIGestureDelegate`. We do this to not confuse the UITableView which, as you might recall scroll Vertically. Then get a reference to the original Center of the cell.
2. `UIGestureStateChanged`: As a user moves his finger to the left or to the right, we need to update the appearance of the cell. By moving the cell's `contentView's` center using the original center reference, and the movement given to us by the gesture we get exactly the behavior we wish to achieve.
3. `UIGestureStateEnded`: Here we need to decide if we want to keep the revealed image, button etc. in view after the user releases the cell, or if we want to 'snap' back. The threshold for this is really up to to, but will be some sort of percentage change left or right compared to the total width of the cell. If you wish to 'snap' back, simply set the `contentView`'s frame to the original frame we kept a reference to. If not, set it to an offset that nicely displays the content you wished to reveal.

I hope this helped in getting the concept across, please check out one of those two amazing tutorials for a more detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use library for such function, i would suggest you to use 
https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell ...

its easy to use and easy customise.

Comment: do you know any to use directly with swift ?

Comment: you can use by creating bridge class.

Comment: You can go through @Jan Greve answer if you want to create it by your own. Using library is the easy way to implement that feature. I have used in my own project too and working fine.

Comment: yes, i will use a library to save time, but it is really useful to know the raw method.

Comment: I do agree with you, i just gave you an alternate

Comment: i think this is the right one for me, 
https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell
 I never used podcast or carthage before, I will do now, i used bridging header with paypal integration before, but how to do it with this plugin ?

Comment: hey may i know why this answer is down voted? Is this library is wrong for the question?

Comment: I upvoted. Simply because I wish I found that lib earlier. It saves a lot of time and works perfectly. It's very clean to have callbacks directly linked to the buttons, too. I saw the lib takes a UIView as well as the "button", that probably means you can customize a UIView and put anything you want in there, pretty useful and customizable as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

The overall idea is simple - your cell's content view is a `UIScrollView` with views on the sides.

However, the complete working solution is a bit complicated and probably too broad for an answer.

I would recommend you to start with an already implemented solution, e.g. [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) (but there are others) and look into the source code. Or just use it directly. Most of the solutions can be installed using `cocoapods` and they work both in Swift and Objective-C.

Answer (score -2):

based on @Tobi Nary answer, this is 4.2 swift version.

```
import UIKit

protocol MWSwipeableTableViewCellDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func swipeableTableViewCellDidRecognizeSwipe(cell : MWSwipeableTableViewCell)
    func swipeableTableViewCellDidTapLeftButton(cell : MWSwipeableTableViewCell)
    func swipeableTableViewCellDidTapRightButton(cell : MWSwipeableTableViewCell)
}

class MWSwipeableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate : MWSwipeableTableViewCellDelegate?
    var animationOptions : UIView.AnimationOptions = [.allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState]
    var animationDuration : TimeInterval = 0.5
    var animationDelay : TimeInterval = 0
    var animationSpingDamping : CGFloat = 0.5
    var animationInitialVelocity : CGFloat = 1
    private weak var leftWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
    private weak var rightWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
    var buttonWidth :CGFloat = 80 {
        didSet(val) {
            if let r = self.rightWidthConstraint {
                r.constant = self.buttonWidth
            }
            if let l = self.leftWidthConstraint {
                l.constant = self.buttonWidth
            }
        }
    }
    private weak var panRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    private weak var buttonCancelTap : UITapGestureRecognizer!

    private var beginPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    weak var rightButton : UIButton! {
        willSet(val) {
            if let r = self.rightButton {
                r.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if let b = val {
                self.addSubview(b)
                b.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("didTapButton:")), for: .touchUpInside)
                b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
                self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "[v]-(0)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
                let wc = NSLayoutConstraint(item: b, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil,     attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.buttonWidth)
                b.addConstraint(wc)
                self.rightWidthConstraint = wc
                self.sendSubviewToBack(b)
            }
        }
    }
    weak var leftButton : UIButton! {
        willSet(val) {
            if let l = self.leftButton {
                l.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if let b = val {
                self.addSubview(b)
                b.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didTapButton:"), for: .touchUpInside)
                b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(0)-[v]-(0)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
                self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-(0)-[v]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v":b]))
                let wc = NSLayoutConstraint(item: b, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil,     attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.buttonWidth)
                b.addConstraint(wc)
                self.leftWidthConstraint = wc
                self.sendSubviewToBack(b)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("didPan:")))
        pan.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        self.panRecognizer = pan

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("didTap:")))
        tap.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.buttonCancelTap = tap

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }


    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let tap = gestureRecognizer as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
            if tap == self.buttonCancelTap {
                return self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0
            }
            else {
                return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
            }
        }
        else if let pan = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let trans = pan.translation(in: self)
            if abs(trans.x) > abs(trans.y) {
                return true
            }
            else if self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0 {
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        else {
            return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
        }
    }


    func didTap(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping, initialSpringVelocity:     self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            self.delegate?.swipeableTableViewCellDidRecognizeSwipe(cell: self)
            self.beginPoint = sender.location(in: self)
            self.beginPoint.x -= self.contentView.frame.origin.x

        case .changed:
            let now = sender.location(in: self)
            let distX = now.x - self.beginPoint.x
            if distX <= 0 {
                let d = max(distX,-(self.contentView.frame.size.width-self.buttonWidth))
                if d > -self.buttonWidth*2 || self.rightButton != nil || self.contentView.frame.origin.x > 0 {
                    self.contentView.frame.origin.x = d
                }
                else {
                    sender.isEnabled = false
                    sender.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
            else {
                let d = min(distX,self.contentView.frame.size.width-self.buttonWidth)
                if d < self.buttonWidth*2 || self.leftButton != nil || self.contentView.frame.origin.x < 0 {
                    self.contentView.frame.origin.x = d
                }
                else {
                    sender.isEnabled = false
                    sender.isEnabled = true
                }
            }

        default:
            delegate?.swipeableTableViewCellDidRecognizeSwipe(cell: self)
            let offset = self.contentView.frame.origin.x
            if offset > self.buttonWidth && self.leftButton != nil {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping,     initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.contentView.frame.origin.x = self.buttonWidth
                }, completion: nil)
            }
            else if -offset > self.buttonWidth && self.rightButton != nil {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping,     initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.contentView.frame.origin.x = -self.buttonWidth
                }, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping,     initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func closeButtonsIfShown(animated:Bool = true) -> Bool {
        if self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0 {
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration, delay: self.animationDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: self.animationSpingDamping,     initialSpringVelocity: self.animationInitialVelocity, options: self.animationOptions, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
                    self.panRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                    self.panRecognizer.isEnabled = true
                }, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                self.contentView.frame.origin.x = 0
                self.panRecognizer.isEnabled = false
                self.panRecognizer.isEnabled = true

            }
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func didTapButton(sender:UIButton!) {
        if let d = delegate {
            if let l = self.leftButton {
                if sender == l {
                    d.swipeableTableViewCellDidTapLeftButton(cell: self)
                }
            }
            if let r = self.rightButton {
                if sender == r {
                    d.swipeableTableViewCellDidTapRightButton(cell: self)
                }
            }
        }
        self.closeButtonsIfShown(animated: false)
    }

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        let showing = self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0
        if !showing {
            super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
            self.rightButton?.alpha = showing || !highlighted ? 1 : 0
            self.leftButton?.alpha = showing || !highlighted ? 1 : 0
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        let showing = self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0
        if !showing {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
            self.rightButton?.alpha = showing || !selected ? 1 : 0
            self.leftButton?.alpha = showing || !selected ? 1 : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer carefully - code-only answers are likely to be downvoted or closed.